# Java Lambda expression - have to cast args?

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

I'm going over examples on Spark RDDs and found the following snippet as an example:

```
JavaRDD distFile = sc.textFile("data.txt");
distFile.map(s -> s.toString().length()).reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
```

However, this code gives an error (straight from Netbeans):

```
bad operand types for binary operator '+'
first type: Object
second type: Object
```

Now, I fixed the problem by casting `a` and `b` to `int` (i.e. `distFile.map(s -> s.toString().length()).reduce((a, b) -> (int) a + (int) b);`), but I'm still wondering if there's a way to do this without casting or this is simply an error in their docs.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that you get a different compile error first; `distFile.map(s -> s.length())` can't work because `Object` doesn't have a `length()` method. The code that actually gave the error that you posted above must have been `distFile.map(s -> s.toString().length()).reduce((a, b) -> a + b);`

Comment: You're right. I "solved" the problem in my exampel with `toString()` called on `s` and casting used on `a` and `b`. Editing the original post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to close this as quickly as possible, so here's what happened: instead of using *copy/paste*, I retyped the example (helps me remember better). However, I didn't use generics, so I omitted the `<String>` part:

```
JavaRDD distFile = sc.textFile("data.txt"); // doesn't work
JavaRDD<String> distFile = sc.textFile("data.txt"); // works like a charm
```

I apologize for the confusion and thank everyone for trying to help.

Comment: accept your answer then, so this is properly closed

Comment: @Lino 11 more hours ... I will, no probs, but I have to wait for 2 days;

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `mapToInt` It converts the stream to IntStream.

Comment: No, but I notices one great thing I did and that is thinking too high of myself :). In the example on Apache Spark RDD docs, they used Generics (i.e. `JavaRDD<String>`) which in turn made everythng very clear. An interesting fact though: I don't see `mapToInt` method for this RDD, only `mapToDouble` and `mapToPair`

Comment: @hummingBird :). You can also use collect(Collectors.summingInt(i->i)) without casting. If the stream is based on Integer value. (there are long and double variants to)

Comment: Thanks for sharing insights @miroh. I guess I learned something from this so I'm not going to vote close, but I'm totally not going to get angry if community decides it should be closed :)